# Windows 7 user permissions

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have Windows 7 on my computer. I want two user accounts: 1. Admin and 2. Normal User

I want to prevent the normal user from:

- Installing programs
- Using USB
- Watching videos on Facebook or YouTube, (they can browse Facebook, but can't watch videos in the browser)
- Using Facebook chat

How can I do this on my local computer with Windows 7?

Can somebody also name the best parental lock software which can block Facebook chat ?

Answer (score 1):

> -installing programs

If they aren't an administrator, then they can't install programs.

> -Using USB

Depends on what you are trying to disable. If you are trying to disable USB drives like a flash drive or other external drive, then Group Policy is a good way to do that. You can learn more about that [here](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_usb_disks_with_gpo.htm).

> -Watching videos on facebook or Youtube, (they can browse facebook, but can't watch video in browser)

Since youtube is pretty much just for watching videos, I assume you can get away with just blocking the whole site. I can't say about facebook videos or chat. You may have to get some parental control software to do that.

Comment: Thanx vcsjones.

Comment: Any Idea which parental lock software will suit my situation, I found KidsWatch but seem like it just monitor chat session, I want it blocked.

Comment: I don't have domain, its just a single computer, can I apply policies to different users ? I cant find it, I don't have Active Directory.